# XMLHTTPRequest fails on Safari and Opera

Tags: javascript, safari, xmlhttprequest, opera

I have three endpoints.
For one endpoint I use GET method and it works fine. 
For other two endpoints I am using PUT method. On Safari I receive "XMLHttpRequest cannot load ..." and "NetworkError:  A network error occurred.". On Opera I get 415 Unsupported media type.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('PUT', attemptUrl + '/' + mode, false);
xhr.send({state: attempt});
```

I have found this https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=327014, but as far as I know, there is no redirection in those endpoints

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code.

- Synchronous mode is deprecated but you are enabling it
- You haven't set a Content-Type header to describe the type of content you are trying to PUT
- You are passing a plain object to `send` instead of one of the data formats it accepts

Probably you are trying to PUT a JSON text, so you need to set the content-type for JSON and encode your object as JSON.

```
const data = {state: attempt};
const json = JSON.encode(data);
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('PUT', attemptUrl + '/' + mode);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.send(json);
```

Comment: @piokub — Then the API doesn't support JSON. This answer assumes it does because JSON is the closest media format to what it looked like you were trying to do.

Comment: Can you explain to me why it works on chrome, friefox and IE and only Safari and Opera gives problem?